# Deploying SQL DB To Azure Timeout Enabling Indexes

Tags: c#, .net, database, azure, azure-sql-database

We have a project we are hosting in Azure, we have our SQL servers stored in an elastic pool. The database we have is generated from Code First migrations from the .NET framework; and we load the data into the database with some SQL import scripts.

The issue comes into deploying the database to the Azure. We have tried using SQL Server Management Studio on a dev machine and on the sql server. We have attempted to push the database to Azure using the Deploy Database to Microsoft SQL Azure, and attempted to connect directly to the Azure and Import Data Tier Application using a BACPAC. SQL server 2014 12.0.4439.1 is our server version.

During the deployment process everything seems to go very quickly and the schema is created, data is loaded into the tables, but it hangs on "Enabling Indexes" for most of the process time and at about an hour the entire process times out and fails. I receive 3 errors; the first was error 0; something very cryptic about database files targeting SQL server 2014 having known compatibility with SQL azure v12. Another about a timeout, with a generic message that the process has timed out. The final error is a comment

```
Could not import package.
Error SQL72016: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:

Bulk data is loaded
```

After doing some research I saw a few others complaining that if the basic tier is used that there are not enough DTU's for the process to run within the time limit. We are using the Standard 1 tier for our database and have tried upping it to S2 for the import process as a test. While things seemed to happen faster we had the same issue. Database is 1.6 gigs and does have 2 large tables with ~1 mill rows; though I do not see this as being such a large database that this process should fail.

Comment: Ran the process again so I could get the exact error messages
 
Warning SQL0: A project which specifies SQL Server 2014 as the target platform may experience compatibility issues with Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.

Error SQL72016: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated.

Error SQL72045: Script Execution Error. The executed script:
/*
Data is bulk loaded at this point in the deployment execution
*/
(Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)

Comment: I was able to use the SQL Database Migration Wizard at http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/ to make a copy of my database and have it checked for compaitibility issues and it also uploaded it to Azure with the data. You are also supposed to be able to the SQL Server 2016 Upgrade Advisor to do the same thing but I did not test this.

Comment: Can you also post the errors,we never saw issue with table sizes more than your table at same tier as yours.

Comment: I also recommend uploading the bacpac to storage once all validations have passed and import it from there

Comment: @TheGameiswar I did post the exact the error messages I received in my first comment. I have attempted using the bacpac and the uploader but I have not attempted uploading the bacpac to Blob storage and then running the import from there. At this point I strongly believe there was a compatibility issue with using a Bacpac.

Answer (score 3):

Not a direct solution to the problem, but I have experienced this while testing large database migrations in SSMS. Extending the resources available does seem help, but that means restarting the deployment process.

Rebuilding all the indexes should be the last operation of the migration so to avoid redoing everything you can perform this yourself with something like:

```
DECLARE C CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
    SELECT so.name, si.name
    FROM sys.indexes si JOIN sys.objects so ON so.object_id = si.object_id 
    WHERE is_disabled = 1 
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN si.type_desc='CLUSTERED' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, si.name; -- clustered first as disabled clustered index will stop others rebuilding
DECLARE @tbl NVARCHAR(MAX), @idx NVARCHAR(MAX), @start DATETIME, @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

OPEN C;
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @tbl, @idx;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'ALTER INDEX ['+@idx+'] ON ['+@tbl+'] REBUILD;';
    EXEC (@sql);
    FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @tbl, @idx;
END
CLOSE C;
DEALLOCATE C;
```

I found the timeout errors occurred with rebuilds that would on their own take >5 minutes. I've not looked at whether this per operation timeout can be configured in the migration process.

<sub>Note that the above assumes all tables are in the dbo schema, if this is not the case add a join to `sys.schemas` in the cursor definition and use it to prepend the appropriate schema name to the table names.</sub>

---

In the comments Kevin suggests triggers may be disabled at this point, though this was not the case on the occasions I encountered this situation. Just in case, add the following after the current `EXEC (@sql);` in the above example:

```
    SET @sql = 'ALTER TABLE ['+@tbl+'] ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;';
    EXEC (@sql);
```

If the triggers are already active then this is essentially a NoOp so will do no harm. Note that this will not help if the triggers are not yet defined, but they should be by the time the indexes are being rebuilt as that is part of the schema build earlier in the process.

Comment: NO! The migration also turns off your triggers (for example) so assuming the only missing step is to rebuild indexes is wrong.

Comment: When I've encountered this issue triggers where unaffected - presumably they are enabled by the time the index rebuilds happen (the point that process was failing). I'll add a note to warn others just in case.

Comment: I did a Schema Compare between the original db and the failed migrated db, and the trigger definitions themselves had all included an extra line to disable the trigger. I suppose the tool makes the triggers and immediately disables them so they do not fire upon data migration. In my case, the trigger definitions themselves were not the same in the failed migrated db.

Answer (score 1):

SQL DB is designed so that you can scale-up for big operations and scale back down when the workload is quieter?  If you're still receiving errors, why not scale up to an S3 for an hour or two (SQL DB bills in hourly increments) get the import done and scale back down?

Comment: We did try this approach, and this did not fix the issue. We actually scaled our server up 2 levels. This did not resolve the issue. Additionally the DTU's usage was only pegged at max usage for the first 10 minutes. Then it entered into a series of repeating spikes.

Comment: Moving to a "P" level server for the publish solved it for me. S1 to S3 did not.

Comment: This also worked for me, by ensuring my target matched the souce Azure Sql DTU/Disk space param. e.g. P2/250GB => P/250GB. This does make it harder to have non prod environments scaled down as you need to do some scaling up/down around the import process. YMMV.